# Can you do pathfinding based on the pixelgrid of a .png file in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, path-finding

TL;DR: Can someone please help with pathfinding with no obstacles, fixed and known starting points, and edges based on transparency of the pixel grid of a .png file.

I'm trying to make a simple app for my students to teach them the correct stroke order and direction of the Chinese strokes.

So far I have achieved this by layering "start" and "end" game objects with `CircleCollider2D` components on top of the `PolygonCollider2D` generated by the sprite to check if they started the stroke, stayed within the stroke, and exited it correctly.

It does the job, yes, but it doesn't animate the fill in process like you'd expect from such an app, not to mention that I need to manually add "start" and "end" points myself.

Ideally I could just provide the stroke sprite, tell it which way I want the stroke to go (left to right, right to left etc.) and let the program create the ends based on the first/last 10% of the pixels, and of course animate it to fill in once completed correctly.

But baby steps!

First, I'd be grateful if someone could please tell me how to even get the pixel grid to begin with so I can perhaps attempt an A* approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the same case for validating AI racers if they are in racing in the correct way. You will have to indicate some sort of waypoint system that has is ordered by the way of strokes you want.

Imagine you're teaching them to write the number 2. You will have to create an array of nodes starting from the upper left most of the number until you get to the other end. You can validate the strokes if their fingers pass through the correct order or not.

No need for a complicated A* algorithm.

However, this won't do if you want to automate everything. This will require you to do some sort of image processing, editor tool, and loads of validations. I wouldn't suggest the automated one though.

Comment: Well, the `PolygonCollider2D` of the sprite makes sure their finger stays within the stroke, it's not checking if they move back and forth like they're shading it, true, but I'm good with that as long as they hit the start of the stroke, don't leave the `PolygonCollider2D` of the sprite, and hit the exit of the stroke.